# How to use setup of a mocked anonymous type?

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following repository:

```
interface IReportingRepository where T: Report
{
     IEnumerable<T> GetReports<T>(object constraints);
}
```

and I am trying to mock out a call to this repository as:

```
var reportingRepostory = new Mock<IReportingRepository>();
                       reportingRepostory.Setup(x => 
                       x.GetReports<ServiceReport (Moq.It.IsAny<object>())).
                       Returns(new List<ServiceReport>(){Report1, Report2});
```

However instead of passing in

```
Moq.It.IsAny<object>()
```

I want to pass the anonymous type

```
new {Activated = true, Enabled = true}
```

so that I can setup my expectation that the correct anonymous type is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom matchers with a bit of reflection help:

```
var reportingRepostory = new Mock<IReportingRepository>();
reportingRepostory
    .Setup(x => x.GetReports<ServiceReport>(HasProperties()))
    .Returns(new List<ServiceReport>(){Report1, Report2});
```

Where `HasProperties` method is implemented as follows:

```
private object HasProperties()
{
    return Match.Create(
        (object o)  =>
        {
            var properties = o.GetType().GetProperties();
            return properties.Any(p => p.Name == "Available")
                && properties.Any(p => p.Name == "Enabled");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few implementation bugs that won't be picked up by the original solution:

```
new {Activated = true, Enabled = false}
new {Activated = true, Enabled = true, Extra = "I'm not meant to be here!"}
new {Activated = true, Enabled = "true"}
```

Depending on the complexity of your IReportingRepository GetReports method implementations it may be worth considering verifying the anonymous type's property values and value types are as expected and that only exactly the properties expected are present.

```
var reportingRepostory = new Mock<IReportingRepository>();
reportingRepostory
    .Setup(x => x.GetReports<ServiceReport>(IsAnonymousType(new {Activated = true, Enabled = true})))
    .Returns(new List<ServiceReport>(){Report1, Report2});
```

Where the IsAnonymousType method is:

```
private static object IsAnonymousType(object expected)
{
    return Match.Create(
        (object actual) =>
        {
            if (expected == null)
            {
                if (actual == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else if (actual == null)
                return false;

            var expectedPropertyNames = expected.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name);
            var expectedPropertyValues = expected.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(expected, null));
            var actualPropertyNames = actual.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name);
            var actualPropertyValues = actual.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(actual, null));

            return expectedPropertyNames.SequenceEqual(actualPropertyNames)
                && expectedPropertyValues.SequenceEqual(actualPropertyValues);
        });
}
```